How to avoid WSREP downtime during log rotation?
I'm running a Galera cluster in MariaDB 10.4 on an old CentOS 7 server.
The out-of-the-box logrotate config installed from the MariaDB repo is as follows:
/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.log {
    # create 600 mysql mysql
    su mysql mysql
    notifempty
    daily
    rotate 3
    missingok
    compress
    postrotate
      # just if mysqld is really running
      if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
        /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping &>/dev/null
      then
        /usr/bin/mysqladmin --local flush-error-log \
            flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log
      fi
    endscript
}

During rotation (I suspect during postrotate) other nodes in the cluster experience timeouts and ultimate produce WSREP errors. Although this is only temporary (about 10 seconds to resolve itself) it causes enough application downtime for my monitors to wake me up in the middle of the night.
The mysqld.log entries at the time of rotation look like this:
2024-09-04  3:14:55 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT3.12579S), skipping check
2024-09-04  3:15:12 0 [Note] WSREP: (57a31a8f-a793, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer b03326d4-98f5 with addr tcp://192.168.196.190:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 11606 rttvar: 17567 rto: 213333 lost: 0 last_data_recv: 11604 cwnd: 10 last_queued_since: 11604000799 last_delivered_since: 11603931517 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 segment: 0 messages: 0
2024-09-04  3:15:14 0 [Note] WSREP: (57a31a8f-a793, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer e65984cb-ac75 with addr tcp://192.168.128.147:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 15475 rttvar: 20546 rto: 216666 lost: 0 last_data_recv: 1604 cwnd: 10 last_queued_since: 71243 last_delivered_since: 13205755173 send_queue_length: 1 send_queue_bytes: 212 segment: 0 messages: 1
2024-09-04  3:15:14 0 [Note] WSREP: (57a31a8f-a793, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: tcp://192.168.128.147:4567 tcp://192.168.196.190:4567

Then (after reconnecting) a state transfer is performed, and my application (mysql driver) reports:
(08S01/1047) WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use

I note that on another server running MariaDB 10.5 on Rocky Linux 9 (although not using Galera) there is a different postrotate script, as follows:
postrotate
# just if mariadbd is really running
    if [ -e /run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ]
    then
       kill -1 $(</run/mariadb/mariadb.pid)
    fi
endscript


What is the correct way to handle the log rotation without downtime?

Both MariaDB 10.4 and CentOS 7 are end of life

Thanks, I'm aware of this.

Tim, in this SE site questions about unsupported hardware or software are unacceptable.

Do you get the timeouts if you take out "compress"?
